# Unexpected round() return

Tags: php

I am trying to round down a number using PHP's round() function. Here is the code I am using:

```
$line_item_price = 13.775;

echo round($line_item_price, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN);
```

Now when I run the code like this I am hoping to get the output 13.77, except I am getting 0 (or nothing -- not sure which yet).

Now when I remove the PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN I get 13.78. Anyone see what I am doing wrong here? It seems like this should be working correctly.

Comment: Are you running at least PHP 5.3?

Comment: The mode parameter was introduced in version 5.3, therefore it will not work for you. You'll have to find a custom function to do what you are looking for.

Comment: I see that in the doc page now. Thanks. If you put that in a response I will give you the check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The mode parameter was introduced in version 5.3, therefore it will not work for you. You'll have to find a custom function to do what you are looking for.

Answer (score 1):

You are using a function that is not yet available in your current version of PHP. One way to solve this problem is using the [`floor`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.floor.php) function.

```
$line_item_price = 13.775;
echo floor($line_item_price * 100) / 100;
```

What I'm doing here is too first multiply the value with 100 and then floor the value. This will give you a rounded down value with the precision of 2. Then to get the correct value you need to devide with 100.

The number 100 comes from the `power(10, desired precision)`

Answer (score 0):

can you not just do:

```
echo round($line_item_price, 2)
```

?

I'm not 100% sure but I think the ROUND_HALF_DOWN etc are for fractions such as 1.5, 2.5 and integers.

Comment: That gives me 13.78. I want 13.77.

Comment: my apologies, give me one moment

Comment: the only thing I can think of is to check if the last digit of the variable is a 5 and if so, you can just remove it. Not sure if that's of any use to you.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a way to do it:

```
$num = 13.775;
$tmp = intval($num*1000);
$dec = $tmp % 10;
if ($dec > 5) {
    $rounded = (1+intval($tmp/10))/100;
} else {
    $rounded = intval($tmp/10)/100;
}
echo $rounded,"\n";
```

This gives : `13.77` for `$num=13.775` and `13.78` for `$num=13.776`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, I'm kind of surprised that it works at all, since the number 13.775 is not exactly representable in floating point:

```
$ php -r 'printf("%.40f\n", 13.775);'
13.7750000000000003552713678800500929355621
```

Indeed, it seems that `round()` is a bit lax about what counts as "half":

```
$ php -r 'echo round(13.77500000000001, 2, PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN) . "\n";'
13.77
```

Anyway, if your PHP doesn't support `PHP_ROUND_HALF_DOWN`, here's a simple kluge that gives approximately the same functionality:

```
function round_half_down ( $num, $digits ) {
    $mul = pow( 10, $digits );
    return ceil( $num * $mul - 0.5 ) / $mul;
}
```

This does turn out to work as one would naively expect, but is slightly stricter than `round()`: `round_half_down(13.775, 2) == 13.77`, but `round_half_down(13.77500000000001, 2) == 13.78`.  Also, as a curious edge case, `round_half_down(0.001, 2)` returns `-0`.  If you don't like that, you can always pass the return value through `sprintf("%.{$digits}F")` to format it nicely.